# How to create 3 columns in the drop-down list using jQuery UI selectMenu widget?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I was given a task for creating a drop-down list consisting of 3 columns (in each row) as shown in the below image.

[image: dropdown image]

Now, I realized that the Selectmenu widget of the jQuery UI will fulfill my requirement and therefore, I used the following code (as given on [their official documentation page](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)).

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>selectmenu demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<style>

label { display: block; }

select { width: 200px; }

.overflow { height: 200px; }

</style>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<label for="number">Select a number:</label>

<select name="number" id="number">

<option value="1">1</option>

<option value="2" selected>2</option>

<option value="3">3</option>

<option value="4">4</option>

<option value="5">5</option>

<option value="6">6</option>

<option value="7">7</option>

<option value="8">8</option>

<option value="9">9</option>

<option value="10">10</option>

<option value="11">11</option>

<option value="12">12</option>

<option value="13">13</option>

<option value="14">14</option>

<option value="15">15</option>

<option value="16">16</option>

<option value="17">17</option>

<option value="18">18</option>

<option value="19">19</option>

</select>

<script>

$( "#number" )

.selectmenu()

.selectmenu( "menuWidget" )

.addClass( "overflow" );

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem was that I was looking to create 3 columns instead of the 1 default column. So, I tried two options for aligning the text content inside the option tag.

1. Putting the text inside the span tag.
2. Putting the text inside a table made of one row and three columns (cells).

Given below is the code which I tried.

```
<option value="1">
        <span align="left">Apple</span>
        <span align="center">Mango</span>
        <span align="right">Orange</span>
        </option>
      <option value="2" selected>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">1</td>
          <td align="center">2</td>
          <td align="right">3</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </option>
```

But this didn't fix my problem as I was getting the Output as shown in the below image.

[image: wrong output]

Since I'm a beginner in HTML, CSS, and jQuery, therefore, I have no idea of what to do next for creating a drop-down list containing 3 columns in each row. Please note that I'll select the whole row consisting of all the 3 columns (as shown in the below image) and not any cell of any particular column.Can anyone kindly suggest what can be done to fix this problem and create the dropdown list as shown in the first image?

Comment: I'd have to say I wouldn't be using a `select` here. It looks to me as though you just have a`table`. No need to complicate matters

Comment: But it is a dropdown list actually, and I've to use the `select` here for that. What according to you should I use instead? I can't imagine how the table will work alone here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, we will want to create a proper HTML Structure. There is an element of select you will want to learn about: `<optgroup>`. Here is a basic suggested structure.

```html
<label for="options">Select an Option:</label>
<select id="options">
  <optgroup label="PREFERRED OPTIONS">
    <option value="L">Standard Screw Adjustment</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="STANDARD OPTIONS">
    <option value="C">Tamper Resistant - Factory Set</option>
    <option value="K">Handknob</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ADDITIONAL OPTIONS">
    <option value="F">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is just the start. You can use `$("#options").selectmenu();` and you get a lot closer to what you want. We still need to add more elements and incorporate the extra data.

> The selectmenu widget is built with the widget factory and can be extended. When extending widgets, you have the ability to override or add to the behavior of existing methods.

This is exactly what we will do, taking an example from `.autocomplete()`. See this example here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

We will perform the same type of override within `.selectmenu()`. The widget factory and it's code can be a bit advanced and a bit hard to understand sometimes, so you'll have to dig through this more on your own.

**HTML**

```
<label for="options">Select an Option:</label>
<select id="options">
  <optgroup label="PREFERRED OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="L" data-price="$0.00" value="L">Standard Screw Adjustment</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="STANDARD OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="C" data-price="$5.00" value="C">Tamper Resistant - Factory Set</option>
    <option data-short="K" data-price="$6.00" value="K">Handknob</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ADDITIONAL OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="F" data-price="-$4.00" value="F">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

What you see above is sort of extended from what we built first. I have added `data` attributes. They do not mean much to our HTML yet they can be useful for our jQuery. the benefit here is that if we encounter a browser that does not support JavaScript (and hence cannot load the jQuery library), the code will fall back to basic HTML Markup and still be a similar experience for the user.

**CSS**

```
.ui-selectmenu-category {
  color: #5F5F5F;
  padding: .5em .25em;
}
.ui-menu-item {
}
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2px;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  background-color: #E4EBF1;
  color: #000;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active.short {
  color: #2E6D99;
}

.ui-menu-item div.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  width: 295px;
}

.ui-menu-item .short {
  color: #2E6D99;
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 30px;
  padding-left: .5em;
}

.ui-menu-item .price {
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: -6px;
}
```

We're going to override and extend a number of theme elements for the `.selectmenu()`. this is all just to help make it fit the look and feel desired.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.mySelectMenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li, name, short, price;
        if (item.optgroup != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-selectmenu-category'>" + item.optgroup + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.optgroup;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        console.log(ul);
        name = li.text();
        short = item.element.data("short");
        price = item.element.data("price");
        console.log(li, short, price);
        li.prepend($("<span>", {
          class: "short"
        }).html(short));
        li.append($("<span>", {
          class: "price"
        }).html(price));
        if (item.optgroup) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.optgroup + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $("#options").mySelectMenu({
    width: 400
  });
});
```

**Working Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sn1z5vzn/7/

Here is where we're taking the `$.ui.selectmenu` and extending it to our own use. You can see we're only writing a function for the `_renderMenu` extension point. Everything else about the selectmenu will be carried through untouched.

This is important since we'll need to define a `width` option. We need to know the width so that we can create proper columns, essentially.

This will go through each of the `items` and create `li` elements to be used with the `ul` that is created by selectmenu. The resulting items will look like:

```
<li aria-label="PREFERRED OPTIONS : Standard Screw Adjustment" class="ui-menu-item">
  <span class="short ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="option">L</span>
  <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active">Standard Screw Adjustment</div>
  <span class="price ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option">$0.00</span>
</li>
```

jQuery UI does a lot of extra work for us, assigning unique IDs and applying hover classes, etc. Our additions allow us to style and theme different parts of each item.

The category items don't want to play well. So far, I found if I try to add any HTML element into it's `li`, it cannot render the rest of the menu properly. I may go back and see if `_renderItem` will help here.

Easy, right!? Comment if you have questions.

**References**

- [Selectmenu Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-_renderMenu)
- [Autocomplete Category Demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories)
- [HTML <optgroup> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)
- [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

---

**Update**

If you change your Option like so:

```
<option data-icon-url="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&r=g&s=16" data-price="$0.00" value="L">Standard Screw Adjustment</option>
```

You can then update the `<span>` to use this as it's background.

**CSS Snippet**

```
.ui-menu-item .icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center center; 
  color: #2E6D99;
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 30px;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

**JavaScript Snippet**

```
    li.prepend($("<span>", {
      class: "icon",
      style: "background-image: url('" + iconUrl + "')"
    }).html("&nbsp;"));
```

The `&nbsp;` renders a Non-breaking Space character.

> A common character entity used in HTML is the non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`
>
> A non-breaking space is a space that will not break into a new line.
>
> Two words separated by a non-breaking space will stick together (not break into a new line). This is handy when breaking the words might be disruptive.

- [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sn1z5vzn/12/

Comment: A big thanks to you for providing such a wonderful answer. It will take me a few more days to get familiar with jQuery, Javascript and its widgets. However, I just need to ask one more question from you. 
What should I add in the code for including an image icon in the left/right corner of each row? as I have done [here](https://codepen.io/DG4/pen/NwVmbP). Sorry if it seems stupid, but I am confused on how to add the image icon in the code provided by you.

Comment: Basically, the content of span `"short"` would contain the Icon. Can you provide some details, like a link to an icon you'd use, or it's size? I can then update my answer.

Comment: Please find the link in my first comment. I want to add an image icon like that.

Comment: @DG4 this drop down has very different data values that your initial example. Will work on it, yet it's rather confusing now.

Comment: No, actually your method is absolutely perfect and it gave me what I want. I just want to add the image icons with it as also shown on this link: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

Comment: Can you please explain what `$.ui.selectmenu` is doing here?

Comment: @DG4 this is explained here: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/

Comment: Thanks, can you answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757905/how-to-repeat-the-jquery-dropdown-list-widget-multiple-times-in-the-angular-4

Comment: I don't use Angular 4 at all.

Comment: Ok, well I am confused on another thing also. How the attributes such as "data-price", "data-short" are linked with '.price', '.short' in CSS? Is there any specific reason for using this word 'data' or is it included in the rule?

Comment: @DG4 Please review: http://api.jquery.com/data/ When adding this to your HTML, they can be readt using `.data()` in jQuery. There is a specific reason for using `data`.

Comment: @DG4 the `data-*` attributes have no relationship with the classes or CSS.

Comment: Also, I don't see any use of the value attribute here in the HTML file. Since only the data-short attribute suffices on its part. Can you explain why you have added the value attribute?

Comment: Refer to the part that discus failing back to non JavaScript browsing. Plus once selected its going to set the select value to that options value.

Comment: On hovering, the items of the hovered row are moving slightly towards the left on your jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sn1z5vzn/7/
How to fix it? i want to keep those elements fixed on hovering. Please help.

Comment: I also want to add an optgroup label next to the STANDARD OPTIONS named as PRICES over the prices list for each group in dropdown list. How to do that?

Comment: @DG4 when hovering over the items, another class is applied to the item, this is most likely adding or removing a border. I challenge you to find and fix it on your own; this is your project. Not sure what you mean in the other comment, but I did address the PRICE header issue in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to fix this hover issue on my own. But you didn't address the PRICE header issue. I've read your answer twice and I'm sure of that. Please see the first image in my question details. The PRICE header is also there aligned to the extreme right of the PREFERRED OPTIONS.
Can you please help me in fixing this issue? I'll fix the first issue by myself. But please help me to fix this as I've to complete this project in the next 1 hour.

Comment: @DG4 "*The category items don't want to play well. So far, I found if I try to add any HTML element into it's `li`, it cannot render the rest of the menu properly. I may go back and see if _renderItem will help here.*"

Comment: Ok, don't forget to tell me if you have any solution in your mind.

Comment: @DG4 one possible hack way of doing it would be to use the `:after` psuedo class and add `content: "PRICE"` that has a negative margin to the `.ui-selectmenu-category` items.

Comment: I used this: `.ui-selectmenu-category::after {
  content: "PRICE";
  margin: 190px;
}` I didn't get the desired result from this code as the PRICE header was dependent on the length of the first header. Is that what you are saying or something else? I don't understand how you will you specify a negative margin?

Comment: This worked: `.ui-selectmenu-category::after {
  content: "PRICE";
  float:right;
  padding-right: 40px;
}`

Comment: Hey @Twisty, there's a problem. When I select an option (except the first) in the dropdown list and then click on the menu button again, then automatically, the first option becomes selected, why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid HTML and I assume most browser will ignore that.

Use an extension point if you want to change the rendering:
http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-_renderItem

Comment: But I am confused on how to use it for displaying the multiple columns. Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm a beginner. Can you please provide me some details on that?